# Sql select order by other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order "contact" table by the "contactreply" table.
The "contactid" row in "contactreply" table is the "ID" row in the "contact" table. "Contact" has to be ordered by the last insert in the table "contactreply" where the "contactid" is the "ID" in the table "contact".

contact table:

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| ID | userid | subject  | content  |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 |      1 | subject  | subject  |
|  2 |      1 | subject2 | subject2 |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

reply table

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
| ID | userid | contactid | content |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |         1 | reply1  |
|  2 |      1 |         2 | reply2  |
|  3 |      1 |         1 | fasd    |
|  4 |      1 |         2 | asdf    |
|  5 |      1 |         2 | f       |
|  6 |      1 |         1 | asdf    |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I tried my best to explain it and hope you understand it ;)
I allready looked at the other posts but I can't get it to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show your expected output, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean with 'has to be ordered by the last insert in the table "contactreply"' ? Contract reply hasn't a temporal column and the only way to order by "last insert" seems to order the contract reply ID in descending order... Is that correct?

Comment: @medveshonok117 assuming id is auto-incremented, then it has an innate temporality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM contacts c 
  JOIN reply x 
    ON x.contactid = c.id 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) max_id FROM reply GROUP BY contactid ) y 
    ON y.max_id = x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY x.id;
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| ID | userid | subject  | content  |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  2 |      1 | subject2 | subject2 |
|  1 |      1 | subject  | subject  |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is what you expect

```
select a.*, b.id from contact as a 
        inner join 
(select * from contactReply as x 
 where x.id = 
           (select max(id) from contactReply as y 
             where x.contactid = y.contactid)
 ) as b
on a.ID = b.contactId 
order by b.id
```

Comment: Note that uncorrelated subqueries are often faster.